# python data structure with sparse series

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I am iteratively processing some data as follows:

1. Do some processing and generate the results as such

   `~~~timestamp1
   a  0.3
   b  0.2
   c  0.4`
2. Do some further processing, the results shall be

   `~~~timestamp1 timestamp2
   a  0.3
   b  0.2        0.3
   c  0.4
   d             0.1`
3. Do some further processing, the results shall be

   `~~~timestamp1 timestamp2 timestamp3
   a  0.3                   0.1
   b  0.2        0.3
   c  0.4
   d             0.1
   e                        0.5
   f                        0.2
   g                        0.6`

That means, **each step adds a new column. The row may also grow**. The point is, in each column there would be only a part of the data having values. The others not, therefore **SparseSeries** seems be a fit data structure for this.

=== Question ===

The question is, how can such a SparseSeries be generated in a successive manner?

Thanks!

Note:

At each time step there will be a new sequence generated, such as [('b', 0.3), ('d', 0.1)]. My goal is to store them in a unified data structure such as a SparseSerie.

Comment: What is the rule you are using to generate this new series?

Comment: At each time step there will be a new sequence generated, such as [('b', 0.3), ('d', 0.1)].

Comment: Yes, but how do you pick those random numbers and letters?

Comment: Is the third case on SparseSeries, or 3?  Have far have you gotten reading the SparseSeries (and Sparse data frame) documentation and examples?

Comment: > but how do you pick those random numbers and letters? They are the results of the data processing. There are documents streamed in every step. So we do not know in advance what the letter will be (it can be a word or a phrase too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create and merge successive SparseDataFrames using index as keys.

```
import pandas as pd

# suppose you have successive inputs like below
# I put some differently-sized lists for demonstration purpose
ps = [[('a', 0.1)], 
      [('b', 0.2), ('c', 0.3)], 
      [('d', 0.4), ('e', 0.5), ('f', 0.8)], 
      [('a', 0.7), ('b', 0.8), ('c', 0.9)]]

df = pd.DataFrame().to_sparse()

# Suppose you will have some 'timestamp' value from somewhere
# This loop is just for demonstration purpose
for i, p in enumerate(ps):
    df1 = (pd.DataFrame(p, columns=['entry', 'timestamp{}'.format(i+1)])
           .set_index('entry')
           .to_sparse()
           )
    df = pd.merge(df, df1, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
```

Now the `df` looks like this

```
>>> df
       timestamp1  timestamp2  timestamp3  timestamp4
entry                                                
a             0.1         NaN         NaN         0.7
b             NaN         0.2         NaN         0.8
c             NaN         0.3         NaN         0.9
d             NaN         NaN         0.4         NaN
e             NaN         NaN         0.5         NaN
f             NaN         NaN         0.8         NaN
```

And we can confirm that this is a `SparseDataFrame`

```
>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.sparse.frame.SparseDataFrame'>
Index: 6 entries, a to f
Data columns (total 4 columns):
timestamp1    1 non-null float64
timestamp2    2 non-null float64
timestamp3    3 non-null float64
timestamp4    3 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(4)
memory usage: 240.0+ bytes
```

Hope this helps.